# jquery how to get the button that has opened the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a dialog that is opened by many buttons. How can I know which button has opened that dialog?

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "Ok": function() { 
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }, 
    "Cancel": function() { 
      $(this).dialog("close");
    } 
  },
  open: function(event, ui) {
    //HERE ::: how to get an HTML OBJECT TO THE ELEMENT THAT OPENED THE DIALOG
  }
});
```

This is called by:

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

I want to know which `<a>` tag has called that dialog.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: i edited the question my friend .. please check it i posted the code that call this dialog 


THANKS for taking time to check my question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler you could store a reference to the element that was clicked on using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), like this:

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
  $('#dialog').data('opener', this).dialog('open');
});
```

Then to get it later you can grab it from [`$('#dialog').data('opener')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), or [`$.data(this, 'opener')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) in the case of the `open` callback (because `this` refers to the dialog element).  For example your `open` function may look like this:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).html("Hi, I was opened by: " + $.data(this, 'opener').id);
}
```

This would show the `id` property of the anchor you clicked on to open the dialog...you can do whatever you want really, [`$.data(this, 'opener')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) refers to the `<a />` DOM element.

[You can give try a demo of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nWdjm/)

Comment: The .live() function is now deprecated, jquery now recommends the .on method.

Answer (score 0):

making the assumption you have a button like such:

```
<input type="button" class="mybuttons" value="Click Me"/>
```

and some css like:

```
.openerclass
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

add that class when clicked

```
$(function()
{
    var myevent;
    $(".mybuttons").click(function(event){
       myevent = $(event.target); 
       $(".selector").dialog("open");
    });

    $(".selector" ).dialog({
       open: function(event, ui) { 
       var opener = $(event.target);
       myevent.addClass("openerclass");
       alert(myevent.nodeName);
       ... }
    });
});
```

Edit: fix syntax error and add another example to make it clear

Edit2: The original was wrong (sort of) in that the opener event is NOT associated with the click event.  Modified to use the click event properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an id:

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
      $('#dialogTrigger').removeAttr('id');
      $(this).attr('id', 'dialogTrigger');
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}

open: function(event, ui) {
     // do something with $('#dialogTrigger')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `$(this)` to a variable like `me` and use it later:

```
$(".locked").on('click',function unlock(){ 
    var me = $(this);

buttons: { 
       "Yes": function() {  
           me.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('locked');  
       }
```